# Python: Get all tuples from list which satisfy some property

Tags: python

I have the following list.

```
[('L', 'l'), ('L', 'R'), ('R', 'l'), ('R', 'R')]
```

I want to find a subset of this list which satisfies properties like "every tuple has "R" as the second entry". I am very new to programming (literally began studying python syntax a few days ago) so be as clear as you can, thanks.

EDIT: this should generalize, since the list above could be with many more tuples, and each tuple could have many more entires.

Comment: You want to filter the list having tuple with "R" at 1st index or do you need a boolean value saying True/False for your property?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
my_list = [('L', 'l'), ('L', 'R'), ('R', 'l'), ('R', 'R')]
res = [item for item in my_list if item[1] == 'R']
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[('L', 'R'), ('R', 'R')]
```

Note that you can achieve the same result with [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), but you should use the above solution (LC is more pythonic):

```
res = filter(lambda item: item[1] == 'R', my_list)  # list(filter(...)) in Python 3
```

Comment: This is what I want. I will accept this answer, but let me just write this in my code and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: OP says *this should generalize, since the list above could be with many more tuples, **and each tuple could have many more entires**.* which I take as could be less than 2 also

Comment: How could "many more" be interpreted as "less"?

Comment: How do you generalize "second item is 'R'"?  You want "last item is R"?  "Any item is R"?  etc.

Comment: @MarkReed But the term *generalized* could be interpreted as that.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, Jin5 said ["every tuple has "R" as the second entry"], from this I understand that each element will contain at least 2 items